# How to establish a for loop in my Matlab code?

Tags: matlab

I am quite new to Matlab and use the code provided on the internet in order to achieve my purpose. This code calculate based on sc = 3 but I want sc = 6, sc = 12 and sc = 24 too. I tried my best and read a bunch of Matlab help documents.

Here is the original code:

```
% computing SPI for stations
%%SPI 3month
td = Abadan.rrr24;
Date = Abadan.date;
% sc: scale of the index (>1, e.g., 3-month SPI or SSI)
sc=3; %%%%%%%%>>>>>> I WANT SC = 3, 6, 12, 24 TOO
n=length(td);
SI=zeros(n,1);
% Compute the SPI for each grid from the prcp or smc data
%For some grid, no observation exist.
if length(td(td>=0))/length(td)~=1
    SI(n,1)=nan;
else
    % Obtain the prcp and smc for the specified time scale and
    % compute the standarized drought index (for SPI and SSI)
    SI(1:sc-1,1)=nan;

    A1=[];
    for i=1:sc,
        A1=[A1,td(i:length(td)-sc+i)];
    end
    Y=sum(A1,2);

    % Compute the SPI or SSI

    nn=length(Y);
    SI1=zeros(nn,1);

    for k=1:12

        d=Y(k:12:nn);
        %compute the empirical probability
        nnn=length(d);
        bp=zeros(nnn,1);

        for i=1:nnn
            bp(i,1)=sum(d(:,1)<=d(i,1));
        end

        y=(bp-0.44)./(nnn+0.12);

        SI1(k:12:nn,1)=y;
    end

    SI1(:,1)=norminv(SI1(:,1));
    %output
    SI(sc:end,1)=SI1;
end
```

I would like to have all output in an integrated place (with four-column). I have attached Abadan.mat here: [Download Abadan.mat from google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13eox7XM_yEexWNSX-Y6-Q88VRI-qldRY)
which you can use it.

Comment: We try to discourage file lockers in Stack Overflow posts. The reason for this is that now that you have your answer, you will be tempted at some point to "tidy up" your Google Drive by deleting things you don't need. That means that someone wanting to learn from your problem will no longer be able to do so, since it does not make sense without that resource. Unless files are huge, it is better to add them to the question itself, using the code formatting tool (and if a file is larger than the size permitted, it is probably off-topic, since it needs to be cut down first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below.

I added a `for` loop to iterate over all the possible values of `sc`, i.e. `sc_set= [3,6,12,24]`, and also pre-allocate the `SI` to a matrix with multiple columns to have its column number accommodated with the number of values in `sc_set`:

```
% computing SPI for stations
%%SPI 3month
td = Abadan.rrr24;
Date = Abadan.date;
% sc: scale of the index (>1, e.g., 3-month SPI or SSI)

n=length(td);

sc_set= [3,6,12,24]; % a set including all values for iterations

SI=zeros(n,length(sc_set)); % columns correspond to values in sc_set 

% iterate over sc_set 
for q = 1:length(sc_set)
  sc = sc_set(k);
  % Compute the SPI for each grid from the prcp or smc data
  %For some grid, no observation exist.
  if length(td(td>=0))/length(td)~=1
      SI(n,q)=nan;
  else
      % Obtain the prcp and smc for the specified time scale and
      % compute the standarized drought index (for SPI and SSI)
      SI(1:sc-1,q)=nan;

      A1=[];
      for i=1:sc,
          A1=[A1,td(i:length(td)-sc+i)];
      end
      Y=sum(A1,2);

      % Compute the SPI or SSI

      nn=length(Y);
      SI1=zeros(nn,1);

      for k=1:12

          d=Y(k:12:nn);
          %compute the empirical probability
          nnn=length(d);
          bp=zeros(nnn,1);

          for i=1:nnn
              bp(i,1)=sum(d(:,1)<=d(i,1));
          end

          y=(bp-0.44)./(nnn+0.12);

          SI1(k:12:nn,1)=y;
      end

      SI1(:,1)=norminv(SI1(:,1));
      %output
      SI(sc:end,q)=SI1;
  end
end
```